# If Statement Matlab Function on Simulink

Tags: matlab, function, code-generation, simulink

I am trying to made my own Matlab function to use in Simulink but I have not success. It is a simple If statement with one input and three output values,all of them integer, here the code:

```
function [ PWM,INA,INB ]  = VNH5019(in_Motor)
if in_Motor ==0
   INA=0;
   INB=0;
   PWM=0;
elseif in_Motor>0
    if in_Motor>255
    in_motor=255;
    end
      INA=1;
      INB=0;
      PWM=in_Motor;
elseif in_Motor<0
   if  in_Motor<-255
       in_motor=-255;
   end
   INA=0;
   INB=1;
   PWM=-in_Motor;
end
```

And here the error:

```
Output argument 'PWM' is not assigned on some execution paths.

Function 'MATLAB Function' (#38.28.35), line 1, column 29:
"VNH5019"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably replace that line:

```
elseif in_Motor<0
```

with a simple `else`.

Comment: If that works if because in that way you tell the compiler that, for sure there is a point where the outputs will be assigned. Probably this solution will work, however I think it is a good practise to initialize variables with a default value.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, I agree. I upvoted your answer for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try to assing a value to the variables before the ifs. Simulink needs values to be always defined in this type of block functions and it seems that in yours they are, but the compiler thinks they are not. So before any if, asign some value to your outputs.

It will probably work.